# JS back button animation

Tags: javascript, dom-events, css-animations

I would like to create a page transition as you can see on [this website](https://www.theoceanagency.org/).
As you can see, everytime the user clicks a link, an animation fires up, before taking you to the next page; and I have already done this thing.
My problem is that I cannot find the way to fire the aforementioned animation when the user presses the back button.

How could I do this in Javascript?

Comment: Could you please provide us some code that you already tried? I guess you already have some kind of project where you tried some of it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Could you please provide us some code that you already tried? I guess you already have some kind of project where you tried some of it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that requires some knowledge of CSS and Javascript:

In your DOM, where you put your links to the other pages, instead of using `<a>` tags, use an ordinary `<span>` and attach an onclick attribute, like this:

```
<span onclick="transitionToPage('https://www.google.com')"></span>
```

(You can use  and href, but you need to parse out the target href and prevent the default event.)

Then in your Javascript, put this code:

```
window.transitionToPage = function(href) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0
    setTimeout(function() { 
        window.location.href = href
    }, 500)
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event) {
    document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1
})
```

Finally, in your CSS code:

```
body { 
   opacity: 0;
   transition: opacity .5s;
}
```

This will have the following effect:

When page loads, the body will fade in over half a second
When you click on a link, the body will fade out and after half a second the browser will go to the next page
Here is example snippet

```js
window.transitionToPage = function (href) {
            document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 0
            setTimeout(function () {
                window.location.href = href
            }, 500)
        }

        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function (event) {
            document.querySelector('body').style.opacity = 1
        })
```

```css
body {
            opacity: 0;
            transition: opacity .5s;
            font-size: 20px;
        }
```

```html
 <span onclick="transitionToPage('https://www.bing.com')" style="text-decoration: underline;cursor: pointer;color: blue;">click me</span><br>
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur, adipisicing elit. Recusandae expedita saepe, hic, facere adipisci unde
        ut tempora exercitationem tenetur cupiditate reprehenderit modi eius voluptatum qui incidunt quisquam
        voluptates. Ab dolores, tenetur doloremque iure sint neque illo fuga eum tempora dignissimos distinctio ex
        doloribus nostrum error at dolore id ullam, voluptatibus ut iusto atque. Nemo ratione ea, magnam placeat
        doloremque voluptas impedit architecto beatae, sapiente sequi dolore reiciendis recusandae nihil. Minus
        perferendis corrupti consequuntur possimus voluptates natus est! Incidunt quae nihil magni corporis, voluptas
        suscipit molestiae modi facere unde excepturi autem soluta? Deserunt nobis nesciunt in expedita, cumque
        blanditiis quam ea.
    </span>
```

Happy coding!

Comment: The answer is helpful, but it's bad advice to use `<span>` instead of `<a>` for a lot of reasons: browsers won't understand what those elements actually mean, screen readers won't announce them correctly, the links won't work when JS doesn't load correctly, etc. Instead, keep `<a>` and call `event.preventDefault()`.